# Split text from one cell to two cells

Tags: excel, vba, split

Hi stackoverflow community,

how would you realize a macro that would do the following

```
A1 "Textcontent 1Information"  B1
A2 "Textcontent 2Information"  B2    
A3 "Textcontent 3Information"  B2
```

to -->

```
A1 "Textcontent" B1 "1Information"
A2 "Textcontent" B2 "2Information"   
A3 "Textcontent" B3 "3Information"
```

In words:
Split a text from a column when reaching the first blanc/space. (Regardless of how many following spaces)
Keeo only the first part in this cell.
Copying the the second part to the cell to the right

Best regards

Comment: You can use the `Left` and `Mid` functions to do this.

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA.  In cell B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1))
```

In cell B2:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)))
```

The drag the formulas down as far as you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub ParseText()
    Dim r As Range, t As String, i As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        i = InStr(1, t, " ")
        If i > 0 Then
            r.Value = Mid(t, 1, i - 1)
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(t, i + 1)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```